# Magento Multi-Site - Split Domains / Move Single Domain New Server

Tags: magento

Re: Magento 1.9.2.1 Multi-site (three domains/ Stores)

I have to split, and move, one multi-site domain to a new server. So the original site will be left with two domains, and the other will be moved to a new server/ domain. I was planning to move the whole multi-site, update database (search & replace) and then delete unwanted domains/ stores. Is this the right approach? I'm new to Magento, and would appreciate some guidance and/or recommended tutorial.

Thanks